# Two rows with two rectangles drawn in one cell. Can it be done?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

It's been some time since I have been coding in C# and in my current project I would like to create a table, which would allow for one column to display 2 filled up rectangles in various predefined colors in each of it's cells.

Is there a way to do this, keeping in mind that down the road:
1) the mouse-over trigger should also recognize each of the rectangles and 
2) the user should be able to select the color of each of the rectangles.

?

I've seen some ideas for text fields, but they are hardly applicable here so if 
anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it?

[image: This is how I'd like it to look]

Comment: Sure. did you look into the CellPainting event? You will also want to test which rectangle either by Rectangle.Contains(e.Location) or by testing e.Y in the maybe mouseclick event.. You could store the colors in a Tuple<Color, Color> in the Cells' Tags.

Comment: @Taw Wow! Thank you! I will look into these options! 
DO you maybe know of some similar sample online that I could look at?

Comment: Here are a few examples: [Basic Cellpainting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253110/cellpainting-checkbox-or-paint-part-of-the-cell/26253861#26253861),  [More on the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441885/text-overflows-for-custom-cell-painting-of-datagridview/51473848#51473848),  [another simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926247/display-header-text-after-cellpainting-event-in-winforms-datagridview/54926998#54926998)...

Comment: ..[a more involed one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204732/c-sharp-winform-multiple-image-in-a-single-cell-datagirdviewimagecolumn/32205326#32205326) and finally one the many folks found either useful or [nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228710/how-can-i-create-a-footer-for-cell-in-datagridview/30234696#30234696).. - The real challenge will be storing the colors and defining the way the user can set those colors..

Comment: thank you very much! Will study these today and tomorrow and look what I can do.